# Does projection of 3D points reduce distances by exactly 1/3?

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry

Let $P$ be a set of $n$ random points uniformly distributed inside
a unit-radius sphere centered on the origin.
Orthogonally project $P$ to a random plane through the origin;
call the projected points $P_{\bot}$.
Let $A$ be the distance matrix for $P$, and $B$ the distance matrix for $P_{\bot}$,
where an $n \times n$ distance matrix records the Euclidean distance
between pairs of points. So these matrices are symmetric across a diagonal of zeros.

Finally, define the distance between matrices $A$ and $B$ as
$$
d(A, B) = \frac{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (a_{ij} - b_{ij})^2}}{n} \;.
$$
(This matrix distance likely has a name, but I don't know it.)

Simulations suggest that $d(A,B)$ is close to $\frac{1}{3}$, independent of $n$.
For example, for $n{=}200$, $50$ random trials led to $0.332$.

> ***Q1***. Is it true $d(A,B) = \frac{1}{3}$ exactly?
>
> ***Q2***. If so, is there some intuitive way to see this without calculation?

---

[image: SphereProj200]

          

<sup>$n=200$ points $P$ (blue) in $\mathbb{R}^3$ projected to $P_{\bot}$ (red).</sup>

---

**Update 1**.
Following @Henry.L's suggestion in the comments, for a sphere of radius
$r{=}2$, I find $d(A,B) \approx \frac{2}{3}$.
This suggests the matrix distance might be $\frac{r}{3}$.

**Update 2**. A histogram of $d(A,B)$ for $n{=}100$, $5000$ random trials:

---

[image: Histogram]

---

Comment: To clarify - are the blue points _on_ the sphere, or can they be inside the ball it bounds?

Comment: @Wojowu:  Uniformly distributed inside the sphere; not on the sphere.

Comment: What happens in other dimensions?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: That is the natural next question.

Comment: Is that what you mean by "proof with calculation"? And have you try uniform on ball with radius 2? It sounds like to me that to sample from a unit ball uniformly can be regarded as performing the Mote-Carlo method to calculate $V=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3=\frac{4}{3}\pi$; If you project these points onto the large circle section of the ball, then the Mote-Carlo is equivalent to calculating the $S=4\pi r^2=4\pi$ with twice as many sample points.

Comment: @Henry.L: Interesting suggestion that the $1/3$-rd (if correct) may derive from the volume formula...

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I will suggest that you try simulation with different radii to make sure 1/3 always hold before you try higher dimension. You are right, the hyperbolic integration is almost not possible to calculate(by hand).

Comment: @Henry.L: It appears that radius $r$ leads to approximately $\frac{r}{3}$.

Comment: I think you want to normalise by dividing by $\sqrt{n(n-1)}$, not $n$: the former gives you the square-root of the expected squared distance reduction for two randomly-chosen points (which is clearly independent of $n$). This may explain why you arrived at 0.332 rather than 0.333.

Comment: @AdamP.Goucher: You may well be right. The variance is too large for my simulations to distinguish between $n$ and $\sqrt{ n(n-1) }$. I added a histogram.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Set $n = 5$ instead of $200$, maybe?

Comment: Using $\sqrt{n(n-1)}$ to normalize, simulations get close to @dgulotta's $0.339$.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No.  In the large $n$ limit, this is equivalent to asking whether the expected value of $(a_{ij}-b_{ij})^2$ is $(1/3)^2$, but in fact the expected value is $2-\frac{3\pi}{5} \approx .115$.

We can compute the expectation as follows: $a_{ij}^2 = r_i^2 + r_j^2 + 2 r_i r_j \cos \theta_{ij}$, where $\theta_{ij}$ is the angle between the vectors from the origin to points $i$ and $j$.  The variable $\theta_{ij}$ is independent of $r_i,r_j$ and $\cos \theta_{ij}$ has expected value zero.  So $$E[a_{ij}^2]=2E[r_i^2]=2\frac{\int_0^1 r^2 \cdot r^2\,dr}{\int_0^1 r^2 \,dr} = \frac{6}{5}$$
We have $b_{ij}=a_{ij} \sin \phi_{ij}$, where $\phi_{ij}$ is the angle between the vector from $i$ to $j$ and the vertical.  Furthermore, $\phi_{ij}$ is independent of $a_{ij}$.  So $E[(a_{ij}-b_{ij})^2]=E[a_{ij}^2] E[(1-\sin \phi_{ij})^2]$.  We can compute
$$ E[(1-\sin \phi_{ij})^2]=\frac{\int_0^{\pi} (1-\sin \phi)^2 \sin \phi\, d\phi}{\int_0^{\pi} \sin \phi\, d\phi}=\frac{5}{3}-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Putting these together gives $E[(a_{ij}-b_{ij})^2]=2-\frac{3\pi}{5}$.

Comment: And note: $\sqrt{2-\frac{3 \pi }{5}} \approx 0.339$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling For large $n$, I would expect that $d(A,B)$ is usually very close to its expectation value.  Since $(a_{ij}-b_{ij})^2$ and $(a_{kl}-b_{kl})^2$ are independent if $i,j,k,l$ are all different, the variance of $d(A,B)^2$ is $O(n^{-1})$.

Comment: The OP did not say in what sense $d=1/3$, so I assumed that the question was about whether the probability distribution for $d$ converges to the Dirac delta distribution at $1/3$ as $n \to \infty$.  I will edit my answer to clarify.